# Sharepoint user unable to upload documents

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an internal sharepoint site with multiple lists and permission groups.
Different permission groups have access to different lists. All lists have unique permissions to with specific permissions groups.

Users in all the permission groups have contribute rights.

The problem faced is that users are able to access the list but is unable to upload documents to the list.
Error message received was "don't have access to this page".

I found a similar problem here but there is no solution provided.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5d63ec32-94f0-4fba-8ece-8627a04dc24d/access-denied-when-attaching-file-to-item-with-broken-inheritance?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do the users upload documents? What page are they navigating to to upload documents? It sounds like they don't have access to that page. Or are they directly accessing the Library (some view) to add new documents? You can check users' permission for the library in question to make sure users do indeed have permission

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I set the unique permission on the list with the default contribute permission, and successfully uploaded the list attachment.

Please make sure the contribute permission level include **Add items** and **Edit items** as shown below:

[image]